# Usage of cscope & ctags in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, ctags, cscope

I tend to use `cscope` and `ctags` on Linux. I just run `ctags -R` and `cscope -R` in my source directory to start browsing the source code.

Looks like it is different in FreeBSD.

Anybody please post the steps to acheive the same in FreeBSD.

I am able to run `cscope -R` successfully in FreeBSD, but unable to run `ctags -R`. Also I tried `ctags *`, but no luck as I am not able to jump to function definitions in Vim with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> - it says "*tag not found*" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ctags included in the basesystem is not what you expect. For ctags you are looking for install ctags from package/ports, it will provide you with exctags binary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So to get Linux like ctags in FreeBSD run the following commands #pkg remove ctags, #pkg install ctags(the first one to remove the base ctags binary, and the later install the exctags from ports). Then start using ctags in Freebsd with exctags binary.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up the usage:

1. Install Exuberant Ctags

   - Using ports (compile from source):

     ```
     cd /usr/ports/devel/ctags/ && make install clean
     ```
   - Using `pkg` (download and install prebuilt binaries):

     ```
     pkg install ctags
     ```
2. Create the tag file

   ```
   exctags -R
   ```

Generally, exctags(1) on FreeBSD is what you know as ctags on Linux based systems.

Comment: If you want to use it as in linux, maybe create a shell alias so ctags -R will call exctags -R

Answer (score 0):

Try using "exctags" on FreeBSD. Usually present at location /usr/local/bin/exctags

exctags -R .